# Open gpkg file in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geopackage, arccatalog

[image]I was sent a gpkg file which I am trying to open.
I followed the instructions https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/databases/connect-sqlite.htm but after that I really don't know what I should do. I can see the file opened in Catalog but that is about it. I am using ArcMap 10.4.1.
What I mean is that once I connect to GeoPackage or in other words see that .gpkg file in that Calatog window how do I 'add' or 'open' it into ArcMap so I can see the image and its layers etc

Comment: i am using ArcMAp 10.4.1

Comment: Connecting to GeoPackages was supported at 10.4.1, so that isn't the issue.  You will have to elaborate on "I really don't know what I should."  With more details, and possibly some screenshot to help explain, there isn't much anyone can do to help

Comment: My apologies - I am really a novice and came across Geopackages only today. What i meant is that once I connect to Geopackages or in other words see that .gpkg file in that Calatog window how do i 'add' or 'open' it into arcmap so I can see the image and its layers etc

Comment: From the Map view you can use "Add data", find the .gpkg file from your file system, select a layer, and add it into the map. There are certainly other ways but I do not know ArcGIS well.

Comment: Did you double click on it or right click on it and choose add to project?

Comment: Can also just drag and drop the featureclass from the Catalog pane onto the map pane - https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9HYT.png

Comment: GeoPackage is a vector format, so it's unclear what "image" you expect to see

Comment: Vince, I was expecting to see several layers, like some polygons drawn on land and water with each researcher having drawn his/her polygons on interest layer by layer

Comment: thanks for all your comments but 1) nothing happens when I use 'Add Data' 2) Right click doesn't produce the Add to Project as can be seen on the image i posted 3) Drag and dropping gives an error "Error opening Feature Class, the Coordinate system description is invalid'.

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with the GeoPackage.  If you also have QGIS can you add layers from the geopackage to a QGIS project?  (If you can you might as well export to a shapefile there and use them in ArcGIS.)

Comment: Thanks John, we think something is wrong with it too. a prof who who uses ArcGis Pro in class tried to open it and couldnt. So now i have been given shp files. Thanks everyone for your help.